# Multiple instance on single SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, instance, license

We have a server running single instance of `SQL SERVER` in production environment.

We are planning to create another Instance of `SQL SERVER` in same server.

My question do we have to buy a new license or the existing license is good enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install as many instances of SQL Server as you like on a server, up to 50. The licensing is by the server, not by the instance (it used to be, once upon a time) so you have some freedom to do so.

The real question I would counter with is: Do you need another instance? Most people don't.

Comment: We have both UAT and Prod in single server. Load on UAT should not impact the performance of PROD. So we plan to split UAT and PROD into two different instance so that we allocate even amount of resources(memory) to both UAT and PROD. Is this a correct approach ? Actually this is my real question and problem

Comment: Well, there will be a perf impact if UAT ever does actually start to use load. I would prompt you to install the developer edition on the UAT server and set up another UAT server specifically to keep the databases separate. I don't believe that using developer edition violates the TOS for UAT, but I would need to defer to one of the other site SQL Server experts to make sure of that licensing question. In this case, I would think it's acceptable, as it is for development and not for production usage.

Comment: Nobody ever expects UAT testing to overload production, but you have to remember this is an environment where code may have issues, so you may have bad queries that read too much data into cache, or that don't evict data appropriately, and for any of a dozen reasons actually do impact production. While you can do what you're suggesting, it's not recommended from a professional standpoint, and managing two servers is as easy as managing two instances.

Comment: Unfortunately we dont have or we cannot afford another server. Can we allocate memory at database level I dont think it is possible but just asking

Comment: I don't think so, but there should be a startup flag for it if there is. At the very least, you should discuss with management about the practicality of not having a second server for UAT. Most of the time people are doing this with virtual servers, and Windows Server is licensed for multiple VMs on one piece of hardware, so your IT department should be able to help with that. There's no compelling or good reason to run UAT on the same server as production, except sheer cost, as a startup.

Comment: *except sheer cost, as a startup* exactly that's our problem. I will create two instance and allocate equal memory to both the instance. I know this approach will be useless/fail when only instance(UAT) is used heavily and other instance(PROD) is not used. All the memory is not going to be used for the instance(UAT) though PROD is not using it. Other than this is there any other problem I should be aware of?

Comment: Most of the time you can get away with minimal requirements on the UAT server until you need it. I only suggest that you avoid the need to run them together, but what you should do is sit down and make a list of your needs and how you want to accomplish them. I can't say what you have or what you need, only you and your team can do that. Have this discussion with your boss or partners, and go from there. Where are you hosting these database instances?

Comment: "*Other than this is there any other problem I should be aware of?*" - Consider CPU, disk usage, disaster recovery (DR), the high likelihood of accidentally deploying data or code changes to the wrong environment, eg data fix to live you were meant to test in UAT.

Comment: Have you heard of Azure or AWS?  Consider creating your non-production environments in the cloud.  It could potentially be quite cheap, avoid overload on your server, maintain a healthy degree of isolation between your environments and prevent any unintended consequences.  The elasticity of the cloud will allow you to power down your environments when not using them, thus not incur additional cost.

Comment: @wBob - Disk usage isn't a problem for us. We have good data retention policies in UAT.  Can you expand on *Consider CPU* what factors I should consider for allocating CPU resource how it can be done

Comment: Disk usage as in disk contention.  Imagine your UAT instance pulls a big read from disk during a peak time in prod.  Similar for CPU. If these were virtual machines on a single host, you would at least have some control - but it's still not advisable to have these two critical services on the same box, it's too risky.  What are your approaches to High Availability (HA) and Disaster Recovery (DR) in this setup?